# How to access iframe DOM from different domain in Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView?

Tags: javascript, wpf, winforms, webview, cross-domain

I am getting "Access Denied" exception when I invoke `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync(...)` method to access inframe DOM. But developer tools of Edge browser allow access to iframe content. Then I suppose there should be some way to access cross-domain iframes from WebView. But how?

Any suggestions?

Comment: **this:** - _But developer tools of Edge browser allow access to iframe content._ Via JavaScript?

Comment: No. But I am not limited with javascript. Is there another way to manipulate DOM in WebView?

Comment: No. You should read up on the Same Origin Policy that is built into every modern browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: But developer tools of Edge browser allow access to iframe content. Yes. I can select any frame in developer tools and execute any javascript code against its content